# Can't connect to WiFi

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I recently installed Arch but didn't set it up yet. In particular, I can't connect to WiFi, although it's visible (in Arch). When I click on it, nothing happens. What might be the issue?

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:d2:44:16:42:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:17:29:70:56:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::6a17:29ff:fe70:56cf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: As per Evan, please give the output of the command `ip addr`.

Comment: @Ramesh, done. I see wlan is down, but why is it down by default?

Comment: What does "When I click on it, nothing happens" mean? What are you clicking on and what have you installed to manage your network?